# Elasticsearch, distance field not displaying in result

Tags: elasticsearch

I have manually created this mapping using this:

```
    $ curl -X PUT 'http://localhost:9200/location_index' -d '{
        "mappings" : {
            "nodes" : {
                "dynamic": true, 
                "properties" : {
                    "id" : {
                        "type" : "long"
                    },
                    "idx" : {
                        "type" : "string"
                    },
                    "idx2" : {
                        "type" : "string"
                    },
                    "location" : {
                        "type" : "geo_point"
                    },
                    "name" : {
                        "type" : "string"
                    },
                    "address_full" : {
                        "type" : "string"
                    },
                    "tags" : {
                        "properties" : {
                            "name" : {
                                "type" : "string"
                            },
                            "slug" : {
                                "type" : "string"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }'
```

I have this for the query:

```
{  
    "query":{  
        "filtered":{  
            "filter":{  
                "geo_distance":{  
                    "distance":"20km",
                    "location":{  
                        "lat":40.728199,
                        "lon":-74.077599
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "script_fields":{  
        "distance":{  
            "lang":"groovy",
            "params":{  
                "lat":40.728199,
                "lon":-74.077599
            },
            "script":"doc['location'].distanceInKm(lat,lon)"
        }
    },
    "sort":[  
        {  
            "_geo_distance":{  
                "location":{  
                    "lat":40.728199,
                    "lon":-74.077599
                },
                "order":"asc",
                "unit":"km",
                "mode":"min",
                "distance_type":"plane"
            }
        }
    ],
    "fields":[  
        "_source",
        "distance"
    ]
}
```

My problem is that I do not get the distance as a field in the results. So I also do not know if the results are sort by distance.

Any ideas? Could it be a setting that's preventing me doing "dynamic" fields?

If so, my `elasticsearch.yaml` is something like this:

```
   node.name: "My First Node"
   cluster.name: mycluster1
   node.data: true
   index.number_of_shards: 1
   index.number_of_replicas: 0
   network.bind_host: localhost
   script.inline: on
   script.indexed: on
```

Comment: I've tried this on ES 1.7.3 and ES 2.1.1 and both times I do get the `_source`, the `distance` and the `sort` by distance. Not sure what goes wrong for you. Can you show a sample response you get?

Comment: You are right. It seems that the problem is with the PHP. First, the payload must be part of "_content". Then make sure when you json_encode(), you set the second parameter as "JSON_HEX_APOS", this is to that the single quotes in "doc['location'].distanceInKm(lat,lon)" are converted to \u0027

Comment: Gotcha, so all is good then. Glad you figured it out.